# Why does this proof on the cyclicity of a prime multiplicative group not conclude that the solutions to a polynomial biject the powers of one element?

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, finite-groups, proof-explanation

This argument comes from the first proof in Keith Conrad's [collection of proofs that multiplicative groups of prime-order cyclic groups contain at least one generator](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/cyclicmodp.pdf).

The proof asks the reader to consider an element $a$ from the group $\mathbb Z/(P)^{\times}$ which has order $d$. Now consider the polynomial $x^d=1$; it was proven in the appendix that this polynomial in our group has *at most* $d$ distinct solutions.

There are $d$ distinct powers of $a$ contained in the group and every power of $a$ is a solution to the polynomial, so now it seems clear to me that the polynomial has *exactly* $d$ solutions all of which are contained in the subgroup generated by $a$. And since every element of order $d$ must be a solution to $x^d=1$, then all elements of the group which may possibly be order $d$ are contained in the powers of $a$.

Next, those powers of $a$ are taken and filtered by their order: if the exponent has a factor of $d$ in it then the order is less than $d$, so using Euler's Totient on the number of distinct powers of $a$ we have $\phi(d)$, yielding what seems to me to be the exact number of elements of order $d$ in $\mathbb Z/(P)^{\times}$.

But the proof concludes here that $\phi(d)$ is *greater than or equal to* the number of elements of order $d$ in $\mathbb Z/(P)^{\times}$, rather than being exactly equal to.

I do not understand why this is not an equality. At first I thought that since the polynomial sets a maximum number of roots, that after filtering through the *totient* it is still not established that the polynomial may actually have all the way up to $d$ solutions — upon further thought I'm not convinced of this: the polynomial may set no minimum but the powers of $a$ *is* a set of distinct elements with size $d$ which are all solutions to the polynomial. It seems from this alone we can conclude that in this circumstance the polynomial does have *exactly* $d$ distinct solutions and that we have them all accounted for.

I'm cautious to believe that this part of the proof is <s>erroneous</s> unnecessary, the fact that this produces an inequality is very specifically handled later in the proof, but despite going over this multiple times I cannot understand why it is necessary take this step or where the argument that $\phi(d)$ is not exactly equal to the number of elements of order $d$ in $\mathbb Z/(P)^{\times}$ by this point in the proof comes from.

Note: Thanks to @Lspice for editing this post and respectfully leaving a clarifying comment on my question as well as my misplacement of the question on MathOverflow rather than this board.

Comment: You [wondered](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417826/why-does-this-proof-on-the-cyclicity-of-a-prime-multiplicative-group-not-conclud#comment1072394_417826) on MO whether @KConrad's proof could be shortened by showing directly that the 'exceptional' case $N_P(d) = 0$ cannot occur when $d$ divides $P - 1$.  If we could do that in general, then we would have in particular that $N_P(P - 1)$ was positive, which is the whole point of the proof.  That's, of course, not to say that you can't do it, only that it wouldn't be a mere auxiliary step.

Comment: I made a few edits to the file. Is there a part of the proof of Theorem 2.6 that you think is actually wrong? Saying $a \leq b$ when in fact $a = b$ is not an incorrect statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, but misses a crucial caveat:  it starts with an element of $\mathbb Z/(P)^\times$ of order $d$, in which case we already know that $N_P(d)$, in @KConrad's notation, is positive.  Indeed, Theorem 2.1 states precisely that, *if $N_P(d)$ is positive*, then it equals $\phi(d)$.

*A priori*, though, it's possible that there are no elements of order $d$ at all, in which case $N_P(d) = 0$ is strictly less than $\phi(d)$.

(Transplanted from [an MO comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417826/why-does-this-proof-on-the-cyclicity-of-a-prime-multiplicative-group-not-conclud#comment1072389_417826) at your [suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417826/why-does-this-proof-on-the-cyclicity-of-a-prime-multiplicative-group-not-conclud#comment1072394_417826).)

Comment: Indeed, that happens if $d$ doesn't divide $p-1$.  I edited the file so the hypothesis of Theorem 2.1 no longer requires $d \mid (p-1)$, since that condition isn't used anywhere in the proof anyway.

Comment: Please tell me if you understand what exactly the OP means about "this part of the proof is erroneous". Do you think the OP believes there is an actual error, or it's just not saying something in the way the OP wants (which is not what I'd call "erroneous")?

Comment: @KCd I can at least tell you what I meant - its possible I used the word wrong: I simply meant not necessary. Also thank you for the publication, as it was the best source I could find on a proof suitable for me to build a ground up understanding around the topic.

Comment: And what exactly appears not to be necessary?

Comment: The treatment of 2.2 as an inequality rather than an equality. My reasoning is explained in the question, but the accepted answer has illuminated in my mind why those steps were made and are necessary. I'm  not sure you should chalk it up to your writing more-so than my tendency to speed read.

Comment: @KCd, I did not mean to claim that your proof was in any way erroneous, and I apologise for my loose wording that gave that impression.  I meant only that the deduction of the existence of exactly $\phi(d)$ elements of order $d$ from the existence of one element of order $d$ was correct.